# Why does git switch/checkout not switch branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have two local branches, `master` and `test`. I want to switch from `master` to `test`.

If I use `git checkout test`, the console says

> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

and I'm still in `master` branch.

If I use `git switch test`, the console says

> fatal: missing branch or commit argument`

and again, I'm still in `master` branch.

What's going on here?

**This is what I did:**

- `git checkout -b 'test'` → created and switched to `test`.
- `git checkout master` → switched to `master`.
- `git checkout test` and `git switch test` → I want to switch back to `test`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: I created test branch with git checkout -b 'test' without making any changes after that. So the answer should be no.

Comment: It lists my local branches master and test and also a bunch of remote branches.

Comment: Yes git checkout -b 'test' switched to test. I switched back to master afterwards and now want to switch back to test again. But this doesn't work.

Comment: But in your question you wanted to switch to `test` branch. I'm little confused here and unable to reproduce your output by using `git checkout test`

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: Which version of Git are you using (output of `git --version`)?

Comment: I think `git checkout test` and `git checkout master` seem to work fine. I tried these again and it worked. Are you sure you are not missing out on any information?

Comment: I dont understand git... Now it's working fine again. But I had this problem multiple times in the last months...

Comment: I'm using git version 2.25.1

Comment: When you're in a situation in which things *aren't* working, what is the output of running `git branch`?

Comment: *master   and   test

Answer (score 1):

> [I ran]
>
> ```
> git checkout -b 'test'
> ```

It's not clear to me why you put `test` inside single-quotes here.  If your command-line interpreter (e.g., bash) *removes* the single quotes, you're OK.  If it *doesn't* (e.g., `cmd.exe`, apparently), you'll get a branch whose name is literally `'test'`, **including the single-quote characters**.

To use that branch name, you'll have to continue quoting it:

```
git switch 'test'
```

because the branch's name is literally `'test'`, not `test`.

#### General advice

As a rule, if you have Git 2.23 or later, use the new commands (`git switch` and `git restore`) instead of the old one (`git checkout`).  The old one still works, but it can produce confusing behavior.

In particular, the old `git checkout` command can perform multiple different jobs, depending on which argument(s) you give it:

- `git checkout master` will switch to branch `master`.
- `git checkout -- master` will restore the *file* named `master` from the current branch.

So far, this is OK.  But the old `git checkout` command has what I consider to be a fairly big flaw.  If you run:

```
git checkout xyzzy
```

and `xyzzy` is *not* a *branch* name, `git checkout` considers trying it as if you had run:

```
git checkout -- xyzzy
```

which treats `xyzzy` as a *file* (or path) name and tries to extract the `xyzzy` file, or the `xyzzy/*` files, from the index.  Hence, if you *don't* have a *branch* named `test` but *do* have a file named `test` or a whole bunch of files whose names all start with `test/`, `git checkout` will not complain that there is no `test` branch.

Using `git switch`, you *will* get a complaint.  You will *not* accidentally get `git restore` behavior from `git checkout`.

I think this is what is happening in your case: you have a file or folder named `test`, and a branch named `'test'` (with single quotes), and you're having Git *restore the file named `test`* rather than *switch to the branch, which is named `'test'`*.

Comment: But if git banch prints test and not 'test'

Comment: If `git branch` lists the name `test` without the single quotes, then `git switch test` should work and should switch to branch test (provided you're in a state in which switching is allowed—switching places certain constraints on the index state). Be careful of other non-printing characters in names as well. For instance, if you type in a zero-width non-breaking space character as part of the branch's name when you create it, you'll have to type in the same zero-width non-breaking space character when you use it.